# Unable to Connect to Apache Docker Container

Tags: apache, docker, docker-machine

I have a server running Apache on port 80 (not in Docker). I would like to create a Docker instance that is also running Apache listening on port 2000 on the host. I have run the following commands to create a Debian Docker instance, forward the traffic, and install Apache on the instance.

`docker run --name WebServer -p 2000:80 -t -i debian:latest /bin/bash`
`apt-get update && apt-get install apache2`

After all of this completes, I have verified the port is open on the host (with an Nmap scan). Attempts to connect to 127.0.0.1:2000 are all reset and not actually forwarded to the Docker connection.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an '[official](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/)' Apache image, my guess would be that you have installed apache2 but nothing more...you haven't started the service or anything like that.

You will have to start the service and maybe just create a 'default' vhost inside the running container and also might be worth checking the port if it is truly open.

Moreover, I would try to add the IP inside my hosts file from the machine I want to check and see the result I am getting

Comment: +1, a review of the offical httpd [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/master/2.4/Dockerfile#L235) shows a [foreground process](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/master/2.4/httpd-foreground) being started that could be borrowed, otherwise, build `FROM` one of the official images.